# How do I work with form rules to not allow blankspaces in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have started to work on some validation for my code, and used the docuentation examples as the foundation of my work.

I'd like to add some validation for the user not to just type blankspaces when filling out the form. The documentation handles the "no blanks" but, then you can't type any blanks at all...
I'd like to tweek it, so that the validation allows one blank space, so that a proper name can be typed.

Here is the codepen from the docs: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101

My template:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
      lazy-validation
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-model="name"
        :counter="10"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="Name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
  
      <v-text-field
        v-model="email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        label="E-mail"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
  
      <v-select
        v-model="select"
        :items="items"
        :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
        label="Item"
        required
      ></v-select>
  
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="checkbox"
        :rules="[v => !!v || 'You must agree to continue!']"
        label="Do you agree?"
        required
      ></v-checkbox>
  
      <v-btn
        :disabled="!valid"
        color="success"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="validate"
      >
        Validate
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-btn
        color="error"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="reset"
      >
        Reset Form
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-btn
        color="warning"
        @click="resetValidation"
      >
        Reset Validation
      </v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

my script:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    allowSpaces: false,
    match: 'Foobar',
    max: 0,
    model: 'Foobar',
  }),

  computed: {
    rules () {
      const rules = []

      if (this.max) {
        const rule =
          v => (v || '').length <= this.max ||
            `A maximum of ${this.max} characters is allowed`

        rules.push(rule)
      }

      if (!this.allowSpaces) {
        const rule =
          v => (v || '').indexOf(' ') < 0 ||
            'No spaces are allowed'

        rules.push(rule)
      }

      if (this.match) {
        const rule =
          v => (!!v && v) === this.match ||
            'Values do not match'

        rules.push(rule)
      }

      return rules
    },
  },

  watch: {
    match: 'validateField',
    max: 'validateField',
    model: 'validateField',
  },

  methods: {
    validateField () {
      this.$refs.form.validate()
    },
  },
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a rule that's along the lines of this?

```
const rule = 
  v => (v.split(' ').length <= 2) 
    || 'Only one space allowed'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```js
rules: {
  blank: v => v && !!v.trim() || 'Value cannot be blank',
}
```

You must check if there's a value first, because you can't use `trim()` method on *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow spaces in your string, but not allow ONLY spaces then you should use [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) on the value. `.trim()` will strip away any beginning and ending spaces and return what is left. Then, a simple presence validation will work:

```
const nameRule = v => v.trim() || 'Name cannot be blank';

// " " => fails
// "Test User" => passes
```

Comment: This was a good idea, and I did try it. This solution did trigger every input to fail eventhough the user had not even begun to type anything... too bad, I liked the idea.

Comment: @Emilia You should look into adding the `lazy-validation` prop to your form to prevent eager error messages https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
v => !(/[ ]/.test(v)) || 'no spaces allowed',
```